# Sort woocoomerce products by specific taxonomy term

Tags: sorting, woocommerce, archive

Following are two taxonomies  and their terms :

1. product_cat - p1, p2, p3, p4
2. brand -  b1, b2, b3, b4

So on the archive page of term p4 I want to show the products from brand b4 first and then the rest of the product.

Please guide me in the right direction or give the piece of code

Answer (score 0):

A good way is to read up on [tax queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) from the WP codex.

So in your case it should be something like this, to display products from `brand -> b4`

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'brand',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => 'b4',
            'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Then to display others products you'll have to exclude products from `brand -> b4` using the operator `'NOT IN'`.